# Парсинг с C# AngleSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, парсер, anglesharp

Пишу программу для парсинга одного сайта, использую `AngleSharp` библиотеку. К сожалению документации не нашел, что усложняет процесс обучения.

1. Как используя `QuerySelectorAll` можно вытянуть отсюда именно ссылку? Получается пока только все содержимое `<a ...>...</a>` вместе с `Name of article`.

`<a href="http://kinnisvaraportaal-kv-ee.postimees.ee/muua-odra-tanaval-kesklinnas-valmiv-suur-ja-avar-k-2904668.html?nr=1&amp;search_key=69ec78d9b1758eb34c58cf8088c96d10" class="object-title-a text-truncate">1. Name of artucle</a>`

Делаю таким способом:

```
var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item => item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("object-title-a text-truncate"));
```

2. В предыдущем примере я еще использовал ClassName.Contains("object-name"), но тут же его нету). Я так понимаю надо смотреть по родителю чтобы вытянуть правильную ячейку из таблицы. Так вот и вопрос, как это сделать?

....`<th class="strong">Room</th>
<td>4</td>`....

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал вам почитать, про устройство [DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), т.к. AngleSharp использует эту модель. Хорошо описанно например [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/document)

1) Ссылка хранится в атрибуте "href". Получить это значение можно в element.Atributtes["href"].Value; если у вас все необходимые ссылки содержат одинаковый класс(ы), то QuerySelectorAll может сразу собирать необходимые элементы. В итоге ваш запрос для получения всех ссылок можно переписать так

```
var links= document.QuerySelectorAll("a.object-title-a.text-truncate").Where(item => item.Atributtes["href"]!=null).Select(x=>x.item.Atributtes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

2) Если нет опозновательных знаков для элемента - береться его родитель. Для получения потомков Используеться element.Children[индекс].

3) Ссылка на [Документацию](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki)

Comment: Большое Спасибо. На все вопросы нашёл ответ.